# Determinant of a matrix having a row or columns of 1s

Tags: matrices, determinant

So I read this property of determinants that

**If in |A| ( i.e determinant of matrix A), if any row/column is proportional to any other corresponding row/column then its determinant is ***zero.*****

OR if,

R<sub>i</sub>   =    kR<sub>j</sub>

then |A|=0 (zero)

AN example would look like the following in a matrix format:

| a<sub>11</sub> | b<sub>12</sub> | c<sub>13</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d<sub>21</sub> | e<sub>22</sub> | f<sub>23</sub> |
| 2a<sub>31</sub> | 2b<sub>32</sub> | 2c<sub>33</sub> |

Here, R<sub>3</sub>=2R<sub>1</sub>

Hence, determinant here would be 0.

My problem is what if one of the rows is a all 1s?

i.e.

| a<sub>11</sub> | b<sub>12</sub> | c<sub>13</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d<sub>21</sub> | e<sub>22</sub> | f<sub>23</sub> |
| 1<sub>31</sub> | 1<sub>32</sub> | 1<sub>33</sub> |

In this case, why aren't all rows multiple of third row and determinant not 0?

Comment: Nothing then can be said, except in the general case where one of the rows is a linear combination of the other ones. A row (or column) all $\;1\,'$s doesn't indicate either way.

Comment: The whole row has to be the same multiple of the third row.  So a11=a11×1 but a12=a12×1 and they are different multiples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim $R_3=2R_1$ holds only if $(a_{31},a_{32},a_{33}) =(a_{11},a_{12},a_{13}) $. Otherwise
the replacing in the matrix the row $(a_{31},a_{32},a_{33}) $ with $(2a_{31},2a_{32},2a_{33}) $ does not make the determinant of the matrix 0, this doubles it instead. The reason is of course the fact that multiplying  a row with a non-zero constant does not make the raw to become linearly dependent on the others. Particularly a matrix containing $(1,1,\dots,1) $ row can have any deteminant.

Comment: I think  I get it. Thanks a lot. All elements of row 3 here must be multiplied by a constant to get row 1, but if row 1's elements aren't equal i.e if a11 = a12 = a13 then the determinant won't be 0

Comment: If there is a constant $c $ such that $R_j=c R_i $ for $i\ne j $ the rows are apparently linearly dependent and the determinant is 0. However if the dimension of the matrix is larger than 2 the linear dependence may be not so apparent.